# NextAuth redirects to localhost on Vercel

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth 4.22.0 with Next.js 13.3.0 and the app folder structure. When I'm in dev mode, authentication works fine and it redirects back to localhost:3000 as I would expect it to, but when the app is deployed to Vercel it still redirects to localhost:3000. What am I missing?

This is my NextAuth route file (path: app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts):

```
import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"

// Providers
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook"
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"

// Prisma Adapter
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),

  secret: process.env.SECRET,

  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      // @ts-ignore
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      // @ts-ignore
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      // @ts-ignore
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      // @ts-ignore
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    GitHubProvider({
      // @ts-ignore
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      // @ts-ignore
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.id,
          randomKey: token.randomKey,
        },
      }
    },
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        const u = user as unknown as any
        return {
          ...token,
          id: u.id,
          randomKey: u.randomKey,
        }
      }
      return token
    },
  },
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

This is my handleSignIn function:

```
const handleSignIn = async (provider: string) => {
    switch (provider) {
      case "github":
        setIsSigningInWithGitHub(true)
        break
      case "google":
        setIsSigningInWithGoogle(true)
        break
      case "facebook":
        setIsSigningInWithFacebook(true)
        break
      default:
        break
    }
    await signIn(provider, {
      redirect: false,
      callbackUrl: `/`,
    })

    setIsSigningInWithGitHub(false)
    setIsSigningInWithGoogle(false)
    setIsSigningInWithFacebook(false)
  }
```

I'm calling it when clicking on a button like this one:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => handleSignIn("github")}
>
  <FaGithub className="mr-2 -ml-1 h-4 w-4" />
  {isSignIn ? "Continue with GitHub" : "Sign up with GitHub"}
</button>
```

It redirects me to one of the providers and I'm able to authenticate with them, but as soon as I do that it redirects me back to:

`http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback` which should have been my domain. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Mathias (@user:10176381), did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you register your app to the providers, you add `Authorized redirect URIs`. you probably have only these:

[image]

But since you deployed your app. you should also pass your production domain

Comment: They are all set to the correct URIs according to the documentation at nextauth, and it even states that an env is not necessary, as they will be looking at Vercels internal ones. So I’m a little lost  :-)

Comment: @MathiasRiisSorensen did you solve this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, no localhost in sight in the GitHub setup, so no idea where it comes from.